# Как заполнить только значения без форматов?

Tags: excel

При заполнении ячейки вправо копируется также формат (границы), как я полагаю. Можно ли это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: насколько я помню есть "специальная вставка" -> "Без форматирования" или как-то так

Comment: При автозаполнении копируется все. Копировать, выделить нужный диапазон, *Вставить как значения*

Comment: да, так работает, но только по отдельности, приходится каждый раз по специальной вставке